# In Kubuntu, in settings Konsole-tabs: what means "Threshold for continuous silence"

Tags: kubuntu, konsole, tabs

In Kubuntu 20.01 in

Settings -> Edit Current Profile -> Tabs

there is the item:

+++++ beg

Tab Monitoring

Threshold for continuous silence

+++++ end

Please, what does mean:

1.
Tab Monitoring

2.
"Threshold for continuous silence"

Thanks, Regards
antondhdih

Comment: Please clarify your OS & release; there was no release in 2020-January (20.01).  If you meant 20.10 (2020-October release), Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Answer (score 0):

KDEs terminal emulator [Konsole](https://konsole.kde.org/) supports silence and activity monitoring. This means that Konsole can notify you when there's "activity" in a terminal (for example, when there's output from a command), or when there's *no* activity (meaning "silence") for a certain amount of time.

Let's say, for example, you run a command that will probably take a *long* time. Then you may want to be notified when the command has finished and printed its success message to the terminal. You can do that by monitoring the tab for activity.

On the other hand you may want to check whether a long running command has gotten stuck in some way and isn't producing any activity any more. Then you can monitor that tab for silence.

"Threshold for continuous silence" is the amount of time after which Konsole considers a tab to be "silent".